# Why is Angular http.post converting string value to an array?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I have an Angular JS and Laravel app.  One of my form feilds is an `ng-options` driven select.  The values are strings but when I post using `http.post`, one of the values seems to be getting converted to an array.

I have this in my JS controller for the options;

```
    $scope.periods = [
    {label: '1'},
    {label: '2'},
    {label: '3'},
    {label: 'OT'}
];
```

This is my view for the select;

```
<select ng-model="egoal.period"
        ng-options="period.label as period.label for period in periods"
        class="form-control game-control"
        required>
</select>
```

And then this in the controller to post;

```
  $scope.changeGoal = function() {
        var egoal = this.egoal;
        $http.post('api/editGoal/' + this.goal.id, egoal)
            .success(function () {
                $scope.egoal = {};
            });
};
```

Oddly, when I dump the `$request`, I get `period => []` and then this error;

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 685:
>   preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Been looking at this for a long time now.  What could be causing this?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Egoal object looks like this after the selection is made;

```
EGoal: {
  "id": 268,
  "game": 147,
  "season": 4,
  "team_id": 2,
  "period": "2",
  "min": 7,
  "sec": 54,
  "scorer": 11,
}
```

but the period value is converted on post to an empty array...

Answer (score 1):

```
  $scope.changeGoal = function() {
        var egoal = this.egoal;
        $http.post('api/editGoal/' + this.goal.id, egoal)
```

A function in javascript is a block with its own scope. You need to use the `vm` concept. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controlleras-with-vm

In the context of the changeGoal function, this.egoal is undefined.

Sending undefined as data to $http.post somehow serializes it to an empty array.

Comment: Probably because php "objects" are called arrays? Maybe not in Laravel.

Comment: Ok, I am following.  Just prior to the changeGoal form being loaded I am declaring egoal though.  So I can in fact print egoal to the view and see that the form and model binding are working as expected - changing egoal.period changes it in the model.  All good until I hit the post.

Comment: Inside the changeGoal function, try a console.log(this.egoal). It will be undefined. A function in javascript is a block with its own scope. You need to use the `vm` concept https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controlleras-with-vm

Comment: Ah!  Getting somewhere.  Not undefined but period is coming through as an object not a value.  How's that?

Comment: I don't know what you're seeing or where. What is sure is if the function is exactly like it is in your question, then this.egoal is undefined when passed to $http.post. Use $scope.egoal instead of this.egoal and make a fiddle reproducing your issue if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS uses JSON object by default in $http.post .

You can change the default setting by adding a correct Content-Type header to the config object:

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

UPDATE:

... by simply adding:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        })
```

Or another solution would be:

```
return $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: "/yoururl/",
         data:{
            'param1': "Test",
         },
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }}).then(function(result) {
             console.log(result);
         }, function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
```

Comment: Sounds fair.  LIttle confused on what you mean by adding a correct Content-Type header to the config object:

Comment: Ok, added that.  Now whaen I dump my request I get an array and period is now an empty object.

Comment: array:1 [
  "{"id":268,"game":147,"season":4,"team":"Olden_Hawks","team_id":2,"period":{},"min":7,"sec":54,"scorer":11,"scorerId":91,"assist1":13,"assist1Id":null,"assist2":null,"assist2Id":null,"empty":0,"short":0,"created_at":"2016-09-12_20:35:04","updated_at":"2016-11-14_15:59:08"}" => ""
]

Answer (score 0):

From the ngOptions docs:

> When an item in the  menu is selected, the **array element or object** property represented by the selected option will be bound to the model identified by the ngModel directive.

So, when you select one of the items from the dropdown, your ngModel `egoal.period` is not `1`, or `2`, or `3`, or `OT`, it's `{label: '1'}, {label: '2'}`, etc. It's actually a pointer to the one of the items in your `$scope.periods` array.

Check out this plunker to get a better idea of what I mean:
http://embed.plnkr.co/9cJ2Hy/

Your PHP script is probably expecting a json object like this:

```
{
  ...
  "period": '1',
  ...
}
```

But it's actually getting something more like this:

```
{
  ...
  "period": "{\"label\": '1'}",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey JoelCDoyle.  I am following but I am using ng-model='egoal.period' for the select.  So, when I print the egoal object to my view I do see period as an attribute and the label as the value.  Are you saying that's not actually what's happening?

Comment: Will you post what the print out of the egoal object looks like? You can limit it to just the relevant part.

Comment: See UPDATE in question.

Comment: Ok, this answer is not right then. Since you are using `period.label as period.label` then you are doing it right already.

Comment: Thanks - thought I was anyway - still stumped tho.  BTW - you're a dead ringer for Col. Les Claypool!

Comment: Thanks! See the answer by gyc. That's looks correct